# Entity Framework - Specify Template when Generating Model

Tags: entity-framework, t4

When I'm generating/refreshing my model from the database, how do I specify which template to use?

At the moment, despite having my new template, it still uses the default.  Then I have to go in and clear out the contents of 'MyDatabase.Designer.cs', then manually go in to my template and run it.

Surely I can just specify which template my model should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you should disable the default code generation. The simplest solution is to clear the Custom Tool property of the model file.
After this just run your template.
There is even simpler way: go to the model Properties and set the Code Generation Strategy property to None.